# Modifying System drive for Windows 7 / Windows Server 2012

Tags: boot, partitioning, migration, boot-manager

I have a computer with two hard disks and a dual boot : Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012.

The system partition is on the Windows 7 partition. I want the System partition to be on the Windows Server partition.

My goal is to be able to do a bare metal recovery back-up of my Windows Server without having to back-up the Windows 7 Drive that contains the boot informations.

Here is what it looks like in Disk Management :

[image]

And the bcdedit informations :

[image]

How can I proceed to migrate the boot manager ?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you already have a boot manager installed on Disk 1 and you can just back it up as it is.

The "System" partition listed in Disk Manager is the partition your BIOS booted from, which is determined by the BIOS, not by Windows. By default a BIOS will boot from the first active partition on the first drive it finds (on MBR disks).

You can check if there is already a valid boot configuration on the second disk simply by telling your BIOS to boot from the second disk.

Comment: I just tried it and Windows refuses to boot because "a device needed to boot is not reachable". Error:0xc000000f. Maybe using automatic repair would make it bootable ?

Comment: Possibly, but having the first disk there can confuse things. Does the "Device needed to boot is not reachable" screen contain an option of "Press F9 to use another operating system"?

Comment: No. I had the option to "continue" or "exit". I believe "continue" would have attempted to boot from the 2nd device in the boot priority list. Exit simply restarted the computer.

Comment: I assume then the second OS was installed separately or after the first (Windows 7) OS was installed? If that's the case, startup/automatic repair with the first disk *physically disconnected* should give you a configuration you can restore on it's own.

Comment: The Windows Server was indeed installed on top of Windows 7. I will attempt to disconnect the drive and do an automatic repair. Can I boot into Windows RE with any Windows media ? For instance, if I have a Windows 8 USB bootable media, can I boot with it and do an automatic repair for Windows Server, or do I need a Windows Server bootable media ?

Comment: Windows 8 media should work for Server 2012. In theory any Vista or above boot media can be used to do it manually, but you'd need media version >= installed version (including service packs) for the automatic to work.